# Math symbols and regular text

Tags: greek

I'm using TeXMaker to compile a document in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, my first report written in a LaTeX environment.

For some reason Greek letters are being interpreted in normal text, e.g. when typing filter, I would see an output lter. Is there any place where these definitions can be changed? Here's a screenshot: [image: report_screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This is a problem with your fonts, since `fi` is one glyph in most fonts (so called ligature). Could you please construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we see your full setup?

Comment: It looks like the viewer is using a wrong font/encoding. Try a different viewer, try PDF as output format.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek, thanks, I was using the built-in dvi viewer (evince). Printing to a PDF does not show the same erroneous output, I'll reconfigure the built-in viewer and see if that would make life easier (as opposed to having to print each time).

Comment: @user2742907 There is no need to print the PDF, because there are many, many PDF viewers (Acrobat Reader, Okular, evince, ...).